# Cannot read property 'display' of undefined in Jquery

Tags: jquery

##To make next button have active class when scroll down then use changeState function to scroll the div to respective position and change data-status attribute##

```
let changeState = function(){
    $('.mainContainer').children('div').each(function(index,page){
        if($(page).attr('data-target') === $('.active').attr('id')){
            console.log($(page).position().top)
            $(document).animate({scrollTop: $(page).position().top},'fast');
            $(page).attr('data-state','on');
        }
        else{
            $(page).attr('data-state','off');
        }
    })
}
// scroll to top on document load
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : 0}, 1000,function(){
    // initial scroll
    $(document).on('scroll',function (e) {
        let activeDiv= $('[data-state="on"]');
    let activeDivWidth = activeDiv.height()/2;
        let cursorScroll= $(this).scrollTop();
        let oldButton = $('#'+$(activeDiv).attr('data-target'))

        if(cursorScroll>activeDivWidth){
            console.log($(oldButton).parent().children())
            $(oldButton).parent().children().removeClass('active');             
            $(oldButton).next().addClass('active');
            changeState();
        }
        // else{
        //  $(oldButton).prev().addClass('active');
        // }


    }); 
});
```

});

---

### HTML part having button and respected div having data- attributes to check if it is on or off and data-target to target the id of repective buttons

```
<div class="mainContainer"> 
    <nav class="navigationSection">
        <div class="brandLogo">
            <img class="logo" src="./images/me.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"  id="homeNav"><h4>Home</h4></li>
            <li id="projectsNav"><h4>Projects</h4></li>
            <li id="contactNav"><h4>Contact me</h4></li>
            <li id="galleryNav"><h4>gallery</h4></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="home" data-target="homeNav" data-state='on'>
        home is here
    </div>
    <div id="projects" data-target="projectsNav" data-state='off'>
        project is here
    </div>
    <div id="contact" data-target="contactNav" data-state='off'>
        contact is here
    </div>
    <div id="gallery" data-target="galleryNav" data-state='off'>
        gallery is here
    </div>
</div>
```